# Make an image responsive by only a certain part of it?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

So, let’s say I have an image like this: http://s9.postimg.org/fr6oy6eb3/img.jpg

If I set the responsive of the image by its height, the image stays like this in every screen resolution: http://s9.postimg.org/4hdz3899r/how_it_is.jpg

Buy let’s say I want to make the image responsive by its height ONLY in the red area of the image, like this: http://s9.postimg.org/eq6g91xbj/how_i_want.jpg

How can i make this happen?

Comment: Is the image actually going to be to solid fields of color? If so, why not use `background-color` on the desired HTML elements.

Comment: No, it is not only solid colors. And because of technical reasons i cannot separate in two images.

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid it cannot be done the way that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two images. You cannot shrink various portions of an image, i.e. JPG, PNG, GIF.

This might be doable with the `<canvas>` element which would require some JavaScript. Someone with more experience than I with that element would have to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to split it into 2 images.  Then you could set the dimensions of the part you want to not scale (the black part).  Then you can set the red width to a fixed pixel value, but make the height a percentage.

Comment: Because of technical reasons i cannot separate in two images.

Comment: Can you make multiple images with the proportions you want?  Only have 1 image file showing, but swap out a new image at various screen sizes using media queries.  That would be the only way to keep it one image file showing.  It is not possible as far as I know to change proportions of a single file using just css or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use two-separate images or if you are just using solid background colors like you show in your example? you could simply use percentages.

Comment: No, it is not only solid colors. And because of technical reasons i cannot separate in two images.

Comment: What are the technical reasons? because there simply is no other way to reformat just part of an compressed image file.